# Pandas number of uniques in each column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, series

Is there an equivalent of [nunique() in Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html), for dataframes without having to iterate over the columns? Basically determine the number of uniques in each dataframe column e.g.

```
  >>> df
   a  b
0  x  x
1  x  y
2  x  z
3  x  4
```

would give:

```
array([1, 4])
```

Comment: Are you excluding `df.apply` by saying "without having to iterate over the columns"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()))
a    1
b    4
dtype: int64

print (df.apply(pd.Series.nunique))
a    1
b    4
dtype: int64

print (df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique())))
a    1
b    4
dtype: int64

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()).values)
[1 4]
```

Comment: you can use `count_values`. e.g.  df.column.count_values()